# ¿Cómo restar días de a 1 en 1, a una fecha?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Tengo un textbox, formateado con un datepicker, el cual me entrega la fecha actual , y al hacer click en el botón `$("#btnCirIzq1")` , este debe tomar la fecha, restarle 1 día y enviarle ese dato la consulta.
el problema es que no he podido hacer la operación de resta de fecha, pues probé con esta solución:

```
//toma la fecha actual y le resta 1 dia.
```

FechaAnterior.setDate(f.getDate() - 1);

var UltFecha = FechaAnterior.getDate() + "/" + (FechaAnterior.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +  FechaAnterior.getFullYear();

$("#FechMaq1H").val(UltFecha);

la cual logra mostrarme la fecha correspondiente, pero, al volver ha hacer click en el botón me resta 1 mes, lo cual no necesito, lo que necesito es que cada vez que el usuario haga click me reste un día a la vez

¿Alguien podría ayudarme, por favor?

Comment: Por qué la etiqueta de C#?

Comment: lo que pasa es que al crear una pregunta siempre me pide al menos 5 temas en los que podria estar englobado y para relleno.....

Answer (score 1):

Los datos de tipo fecha en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) pueden construirse desde la cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos desde medianoche del 1 de enero de 1970.

Si a una fecha cualquiera le restas la cantidad de milisegundos de un día, obtienes el día anterior:

```
var hoy = new Date();
var ayer = new Date(hoy.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

console.log("Hoy es: " + hoy);
console.log("Ayer fue: " + ayer);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/f@/LLFIISO/UsFWIS@1XMElsSRVQ9OaCySaWJlahCwMVKWXnloSkpkLVKKgq6BhZKKgpWBmACMMDQwMNIF6uZLz84rzc1L1cvLTNZQ8gGanFlspKClog@wByqNIO4IsSStNhSgAWalp/f8/AA)</kbd>.

Comment: gracias, pero la fecha  si la obtengo del sistema siempre me va a dar como resultado el mismo día anterior y lo que necesito es que ese día anterior vaya disminuyendo en forma progresiva.

Comment: @RodrigoMenares si sabes restar un día (como he mostrado) sabrás restar cualquier cantidad de días.

Comment: si se ha dado cuenta, esta dentro de un click,  su solución lo que hace es tomar la misma fecha y restarle un día, pero hay que considerar, que también debe restarle a la fecha resultante, gracias

Comment: Que sea dentro de un click es irrelevante, tu pregunta (tal y como se ve en el título) es restar días a una fecha, es la pregunta que hiciste y es la respuesta que recibiste. Si necesitas algo distinto, tendrás que reformular la pregunta.

Comment: le hice las modificaciones al texto, espero aclaren sus dudas

Comment: Creo que te estás confundiendo @RodrigoMenares al venir aquí esperando que te den todo listo para copiar y pegar. Paper te dió una solución a tu problema, lo único que necesitabas es *ADAPTARLA* a tu ejercicio. Si solo copias y pegas, nunca aprenderás a resolver los problemas que te surjan. En StackOverflow damos soluciones a los problemas, **no trabajamos para otros**

Answer (score 0):

después de mucho probar, al fin di con la solución :

1.- fuera del procedimiento del click :

```
var FechaTextbox = new Date();
```

2.- ya dentro del procedimiento del click:

```
 FechaTextbox.setDate(FechaTextbox.getDate() - 1);
 var FechaAnterior = FechaTextbox.getDate() + "/" + (FechaTextbox.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + FechaTextbox.getFullYear();
   $("#FechMaq1H").val(FechaAnterior);
```

y ahí funcionó.